# not a dog, but a husky

Tags: meaning-in-context, sentence-meaning

(a) is literally anomalous, but could it convey the meaning of (b) through artistic license or intonation?

> a. Fido is not a dog, but a husky.

> b. Fido is not just any dog, but a husky.

Comment: (a) needs 'just' after 'not' to avoid seeming nonsensical.

Comment: Without 'just' there is ambiguity between (1) the meaning you desire (2) you don't understand what a dog is.

Comment: Please nanm your source. Please supply references and greater context.

Comment: I made up the sentences and had some people check them.